# How can i upload a docx file on server using express js?

Tags: express, file-upload, server, upload, backend

I`m using `express-fileupload` for uploading files in my server. its working but when i try to upload a DOCX file req.files show that it null
That my code for test

```
exports.uploadFile = async (req,res) => {
   console.log(req.files);
   await res.json({
    success: true,
    message: "File uploaded!"
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough data.

Try to:

- Check you use express-fileupload 1.1.6 or later.
- Set express-fileupload option debug to true.
- Share debug output.

You should see something like this:

```
Express server listening on port  8000
Express-file-upload: Temporary file path is /projects/express-fileupload-project/temp/tmp-1-1586420891424
Express-file-upload: New upload started sampleFile->Test word document.docx, bytes:0
Express-file-upload: Temporary file path is /projects/express-fileupload-project/temp/tmp-3-1586420891425
Express-file-upload: New upload started sampleFile1->tmp-2-1586420891425, bytes:0
Express-file-upload: Temporary file path is /projects/express-fileupload-project/temp/tmp-5-1586420891426
Express-file-upload: New upload started sampleFile2->tmp-4-1586420891426, bytes:0
Express-file-upload: Opening write stream for sampleFile->Test word document.docx...
Express-file-upload: Uploading sampleFile->Test word document.docx, bytes:11779...
Express-file-upload: Upload finished sampleFile->Test word document.docx, bytes:11779
Express-file-upload: Upload sampleFile->Test word document.docx completed, bytes:11779.
Express-file-upload: Upload finished sampleFile1->tmp-2-1586420891425, bytes:0
Express-file-upload: Upload finished sampleFile2->tmp-4-1586420891426, bytes:0
req.files >>> {
  sampleFile: {
    name: 'Test word document.docx',
    data: <Buffer >,
    size: 11779,
    encoding: '7bit',
    tempFilePath: '/projects/express-fileupload-project/temp/tmp-1-1586420891424',
    truncated: false,
    mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    md5: 'f5bd86e915e1fed35aba84dc58a2c446',
    mv: [Function: mv]
  }
}
Express-file-upload: Moving temporary file /projects/express-fileupload-project/temp/tmp-1-1586420891424 to /projects/express-fileupload-project/uploads/Test word document.docx
```

I've tried to upload docx and don't get any issues.